# Using @Transaction in JDBI / Dropwizard application

Tags: java, transactions, dropwizard, jdbi

I hava two jdbi dao like these:

```
public interface dao1 {
  @Query("insert into table1 ...")
  findByid(myBean1);
}

public interface dao2 {
  @Query("insert into table2 ...)
  save(myBean2;
  }
}
```

i want to execute save of two dao in one transaction like:

```
dao1.save();
dao2.save();
```

With spring i have used @transactional annotation. What can i do with dropwizard and jdbi ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use @Transaction in JDBI. I have blogged about it here. http://manikandan-k.github.io/2015/05/10/Transactions_in_jdbi.html

Comment: Hi, thanks this is what i need, but how can i test the class that implements GetHandle interface? Or if  a need to use different repository object in the same transaction?

Comment: We can't use two different repository in same transaction. If you want use two different Dao's create a repository containing those two Daos. For testing the class, What is the difficulty you are facing ?

Comment: we can't mock daos in repository 's unit test, because they are injected by jdbi @SqlCreateObject annotation and jdbi.onDemand method. It's true?

Comment: Since repository is abstract class, you need to have a implementation when writing unit test. When you give implementation you can inject mocks for abstract methods

Comment: Hi @Manikandan,

I went through your blog and tried to save the transaction  using Repository class but no luck.

This is my run method :

Comment: `public void run(ServiceConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory.build(environment, configuration.dataBase(), "mysql");
final AppsMessageDao appsMessageDao = jdbi.onDemand(AppsMessageDao.class);
final MessageDao messageDao = jdbi.onDemand(MessageDao.class);
  }`
When I use the repository Class , I get error connection already closed .

Comment: I am quite surprised why such this important information is not a part of official document form JDBI.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The first method always goes through (no-rollbacks) whenever the next/last method throws exceptions. I was hoping `@Transaction` annotation would solve that.

Answer (score 2):

The [SQL Object API Overview](http://jdbi.org/jdbi2/sql_object_overview/) shows the possibility to bind two instances to the same handle. This way you can both `save()` calls as part of the same transaction:

```
// TODO: add try/catch/finally to close things properly
DBI dbi = new DBI("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
Handle h = dbi.open();
h.begin();
Dao1 dao1 = h.attach(Dao1.class);
Dao2 dao2 = h.attach(Dao2.class);
dao1.save(myBean1);
dao2.save(myBean2);
h.commit();
h.close();
```

If you use `onDemand` instead of `open` and hesitate to get try/catch right, you might want to consider something like this:

```
// add some more interfaces
public interface Dao1 extends GetHandle, Transactional<Dao1> {
   @Query("insert into table1 ...")
   save(myBean1);
}

DBI dbi = new DBI("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
Dao1 dao1 = dbi.onDemand(Dao1.class);

// no try/catch necessary here
dao1.inTransaction(transactional, status) -> {
    transactional.save(myBean1);
    transactional.withHandle((h) -> h.attach(Dao2.class)
       .save(myBean2));
    return null; // return is enforced by the interface
});
```

Please double-check the functionality with a unit test.

Comment: The question was about the JDBI `@Transaction` annotation. It is not used here...

Answer (score 0):

As per the jdbi docs,

> Update, insert, and data definition statements are indicated in the
>   SQL Object API via the `@SqlUpdate` annotation. The methods for these
>   statements must have either void or int return types. If the return
>   type is int, the the value will be the number of rows changed.

Annotate with `@SqlUpdate`. Here's a sample usage using h2 as the DB.

```
DBI dbi = new DBI("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
Handle h = dbi.open();
Dao1 dao1 = h.attach(Dao1.class);
dao1.save(myBean1);
```

Reference: http://jdbi.org/jdbi2/sql_object_api_dml

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction callback on DBI:

```
dbi.useTransaction((handle, transactionStatus) -> {
    Dao1 dao1 = handle.attach(Dao1.class);
    Dao2 dao2 = handle.attach(Dao2.class);
    dao1.save();
    dao2.save();
});
```

Assuming you're using JDBI v2.x

Answer (score -7):

Use @UnitOfWork

Example:

```
@POST
@UnitOfWork
public Role create(@Valid RoleApi roleApi) {
    return roleService.create(roleApi);
}
```

Comment: @UnitOfWork annotation is enabled only with hibernate bundle and not with jdbi one.